# Why Apache Tomcat Maven plugin uploads WAR file twice?

Tags: tomcat, maven, plugins, deployment, war

When I deploy my WAR using maven, the target war (exact the same one) is being uploaded to the server twice.
Can someone explain that?

I am using this on my module:

```
clean install org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.0:redeploy
```

From the Log file

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ mobile-server ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [mobile-server] in [C:\develope\mobile\mobile-server\target\mobile-server]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\develope\mobile\mobile-server\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [241 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\develope\mobile\mobile-server\target\mobile-server.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.0:redeploy (default-cli) @ mobile-server <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.0:redeploy (default-cli) @ mobile-server ---    
[INFO] Deploying war to http://myserver.eu/pra-mobile-server  
Uploading: http://myserver.eu/manager-test/deploy?path=%2Fmobile-server&update=true
Uploaded: http://myserver.eu/manager-test/deploy?path=%2Fmobile-server&update=true (12678 KB at 49.3 KB/sec)

Uploading: http://myserver.eu/manager-test/deploy?path=%2Fmobile-server&update=true
Uploaded: http://myserver.eu/manager-test/deploy?path=%2Fmobile-server&update=true (12678 KB at 50.9 KB/sec)
```

My main pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>eu.company.prj.pramobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobile-parent</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../mobile-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mobile-server</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>mobile server</name>

<properties>
    <version.standard.taglibs>1.1.2</version.standard.taglibs>
</properties>


<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libs-milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - libs</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
        </repository>
 </repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>mobile-test</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>mobile-common</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Import Spring dependencies, these are either from community or versions
        certified in WFK2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-cache</artifactId>
        <version>0.8a</version>
        <!-- Unfortunately design of spring cache module is not the best - we
            need to exclude not necessary dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>gigaspaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>gigaspaces-ce</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsk-lib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsk-platform</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>mahalo</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>reggie</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>start</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>boot</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jini</groupId>
                <artifactId>webster</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-attributes</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-attributes-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-attributes</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-attributes-compiler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-cache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jmx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-minimal</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-system</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jcs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jgroups</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgroups-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xjavadoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>xjavadoc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
                <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${version.quartz}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--mockito for test-->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.5</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
      <artifactId>springockito</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
      <artifactId>springockito-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--testing MVC controllers-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>mobile-server</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                <!-- Solves locked problem for JSP while jetty is running -->
                <webDefaultXml>src/test/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
                <stopKey>0</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8001</stopPort>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>org.apache.commons.logging.Log</name>
                        <value>org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog</value>
                    </systemProperty>

                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>log4j.configurationFile</name>
                        <value>file:${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.xml</value>
                    </systemProperty>

                </systemProperties>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Surefire plugin before 2.9 version is buggy -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>true</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <!--to avoid maven error message-->
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--import objects from schema generation-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <packageName>eu.company.prj.pra.mobile.server.generated.place1</packageName>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/META-INF/schema</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                <failOnNoSchemas>true</failOnNoSchemas>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- mvn tomcat plugin alternative - run -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>             
                <systemProperties>-Dmaven.tomcat.uriEncoding=UTF-8</systemProperties>
                <url>${tomcat-maven-plugin.url}</url>
                <username>${tomcat-maven-plugin.username}</username>
                <password>${tomcat-maven-plugin.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- mvn tomcat plugin alternative - run -->
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<contextFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/tomcat-context.xml</contextFile>-->
                <!--<url>${tomcat-maven-plugin.url}</url>-->
                <!--<username>${tomcat-maven-plugin.username}</username>-->
                <!--<password>${tomcat-maven-plugin.password}</password>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
            <!--<dependencies>-->
                <!--<dependency>-->
                    <!--<groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>5.1.9</version>-->
                <!--</dependency>-->
            <!--</dependencies>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATE**
Parent pom:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>eu.company.prj.mobile</groupId>
<artifactId>mobile-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>mobile project parent</name>

<properties>
    <version.spring>3.1.1.RELEASE</version.spring>
    <version.jackson>1.9.11</version.jackson>
    <version.commons.logging>1.1.1</version.commons.logging>
    <version.quartz>2.1.6</version.quartz>
    <slf4j.version>1.5.8</slf4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Force Java 6 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
        just properties with u/p ...
</profiles>
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: try removing your jetty plugin and re-execute, just to make sure jetty plugin is not the culprit.

Comment: @SajanChandran thanks for a try, but there is no change

Comment: There's an issue about this over at Apache (I guess from you @Cabot?):

[MTOMCAT-195](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-195)

No explanation though.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the Tomcat 7 plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try and run the mvn cmd line without the install goal.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced with the same issue during the upload of my war to a test server. I performed several attempts to find the answer on this question in the Internet with no success. Accidentally, I found our the problem in my case and I share it here because maybe this can help to someone (but, I'm not sure if this is your case).

So in my case, the double upload of war was caused by the reason that I've forwarded ports. Tomcat usually works on 8080 port. To force it to work on 80 port I configured my server (using iptables) in such a way that it simply forwards requests from 80 to 8080 port. For tomcat maven plugin configuration I simply used uploading by ip, without specifying 8080 port. This causes maven plugin to upload war twice (the first request was a redirection, while the second was actual upload).

Simply changing the port in plugin configuration to 8080 solved my problem.